# Unresolved reference for some library classes of Cerberus in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, cerberus

[image]

I started running into an import issue where PyCharm is unable to resolve references to classes for some libraries I have installed. I haven't run into this issue for any standard libraries.

`from cerberus import Validator` used to work but stopped working along with the other reference issues.

I have tried:

1. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
2. Using a difference Anaconda env
3. Re-installing library

Comment: ctrl + click on `cerberus`, do you see that class in the opened file ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary when I ctrl + click I go into cerberus/__init_.py and the Validator class is present like so:
`from cerberus.validator import DocumentError, Validator`

Comment: Does the `__init__.py` have syntax highlighting? Btw which PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: @PavelKarateev `__init__.py` does not  have syntax highlighting. I am using PyCharm version 2021.1.3

Comment: @PavelKarateev I went to Preferences > Editor > File Type. I thought __init__.py would be under "Text" but it wasn't. I then added  "__init__.py" to the Python file type under the "Recognized File Types" tab.  This solved the issue. Thank you.